# Background-color hex to JavaScript variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, hex, rgb, background-color

I'm kind of new to JavaScript and jQuery and now I'm facing a problem:

I need to post some data to PHP and one bit of the data needs to be the background color hex of div X.

jQuery has the css("background-color") function and with it I can get RGB value of the background into a JavaScript variable.

The CSS function seems to return a string like this rgb(0, 70, 255).

I couldn't find any way to get hex of the background-color (even though it's set as hex in CSS).

So it seems like I need to convert it. I found a function for converting RGB to hex, but it needs to be called with three different variables, r, g and b. So I would need to parse the string rgb(x,xx,xxx) into var r=x; var g=xx; var b=xxx; somehow.

I tried to google parsing strings with JavaScript, but I didn't really understand the regular expressions thing.

Is there a way to get the background-color of div as hex, or can the string be converted into 3 different variables?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

try this out:

```
var rgbString = "rgb(0, 70, 255)"; // get this in whatever way.

var parts = rgbString.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
// parts now should be ["rgb(0, 70, 255", "0", "70", "255"]

delete (parts[0]);
for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
    parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
    if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
} 
var hexString ='#'+parts.join('').toUpperCase(); // "#0070FF"
```

In response to the question in the comments below:

> I'm trying to modify the regex to handle both rgb and rgba depending which one I get. Any hints? Thanks.

I'm not exactly sure if it makes sense in the context of this question (since you can't represent an rgba color in hex), but I guess there could be other uses. Anyway, you could change the regex to be like this:

```
/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(0\.\d+))?\)$/
```

Example output:

```
var d = document.createElement('div');
d.style.backgroundColor = 'rgba( 255,  60, 50, 0)';

/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(1|0\.\d+))?\)$/.exec(d.style.backgroundColor);

// ["rgba(255, 60, 50, 0.33)", "255", "60", "50", "0.33"]
```

Comment: +1 nice implementation with the the regex match, although I wonder if there's a constant space after the comma across all browsers

Comment: Well, this is the actual answer, thanks. However for me Ipfavreau's answer worked, since I'm just posting the background-color to create a css file with php.

Comment: Wouldn't parts be ["rgb(0, 70, 255)","0","70","255"]?

Comment: I love StackOverflow. Thanks, didn't want to figure this out myself. :-P

Comment: @nickf this doesnt seem to work in IE `parts` always comes back as null and has an error. i made a question on it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5516344/background-color-hex-to-javascript-variable

Comment: @Neal or anyone else having that issue: In IE, jquery 1.4.4 returns the hex code instead of the rgb string. So parts is null because the regex doesn't match, which causes an error when parts is used. I had to add a check before the delete and return the original string if parts is null.

Comment: @nickf this is great; I'm trying to modify the regex to handle both rgb and rgba depending which one I get. Any hints? Thanks.

Comment: I made this a question of its own http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7543818/regex-javascript-to-match-both-rgb-and-rgba

Comment: @nickf forgot to thank you for that from before. btw I added `/^rgba?\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)(?:,\s*(1|0|0\.\d+))?\)$/` the `|0` near the end to check when alpha is just 0 and not 0.x

Comment: @fortuneRice i think it should be `(1|0|0?\.d+)`, since `.3` is valid.

Answer (score 10):

If you have jQuery available, this is the super-compact version that I just came up with.

```
var RGBtoHEX = function(color) {
  return "#"+$.map(color.match(/\b(\d+)\b/g),function(digit){
    return ('0' + parseInt(digit).toString(16)).slice(-2)
  }).join('');
};
```

Comment: Nowadays we don't even need jQuery for mapping. Here is the vanilla version: `var RGBtoHEX = function(color) {
  return "#"+(color.match(/\b(\d+)\b/g).map(function(digit){
    return ('0' + parseInt(digit).toString(16)).slice(-2)
  })).join('');
};
`

Answer (score 8):

You can set a CSS color using rgb also, such as this:

```
background-color: rgb(0, 70, 255);
```

It is [valid CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_units.asp), don't worry.

---

**Edit:** See [nickf answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638948/background-color-hex-to-js-variable-jquery/639030#639030) for a nice way to convert it if you absolutely need to.

Comment: +1 - *if* the color has to be restored on some web page later on, then why do any work converting at all :)

Answer (score 5):

I found another function awhile back ([by R0bb13](http://markmail.org/message/hilbsejsl4zxwlv6#query:+page:1+mid:hilbsejsl4zxwlv6+state:results)). It doesn't have the regex, so I had to borrow it from nickf to make it work properly. I'm only posting it because it's an interesting method that doesn't use an if statement or a loop to give you a result. Also this script returns the hex value with a # (It was needed by the [Farbtastic](http://acko.net/dev/farbtastic) plugin I was using at the time)

```
//Function to convert hex format to a rgb color
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
 var hexDigits = ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","a","b","c","d","e","f"];
 rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
 function hex(x) {
  return isNaN(x) ? "00" : hexDigits[(x - x % 16) / 16] + hexDigits[x % 16];
 }
 return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}

// call the function: rgb( "rgb(0, 70, 255)" );
// returns: #0046ff
```

Note: The hex result from nickf's script should be 0046ff and not 0070ff, but no big deal :P

Update, another **better** alternative method:

```
function rgb2hex(rgb) {
 rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
 function hex(x) {
  return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);
 }
 return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}
```

Comment: I would rather move function hex(x) out of the scope of fucntion rgb2hex for performance improvement. Anyway it's a nice clean solution, thanks for sharing. Have a look at mine below, I would like your opinion.

Answer (score 3):

With JQuery..

```
var cssColorToHex = function(colorStr){
    var hex = '#';
    $.each(colorStr.substring(4).split(','), function(i, str){
        var h = ($.trim(str.replace(')',''))*1).toString(16);
        hex += (h.length == 1) ? "0" + h : h;
    });
    return hex;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

These solutions will fail in Chrome, as it returns an rgba(x,x,x,x) for background-color.

EDIT: This is not necessarily true. Chrome will still set backgrounds using rgb(), depending on what you are doing. Most likely as long as there is no alpha channel applied, Chrome will respond with rgb instead of rgba.

Answer (score 1):

How about this solution, function **stringRGB2HEX** returns a copy of the input string where all occurencies of colors in the format "rgb(r,g,b)" have been replaced by the hex format "#rrggbb".

```
   //function for private usage of the function below
   //(declaring this one in global scope should make it faster rather than 
   //declaraing it as temporary function inside stringRGB2HEX that need to be
   //instantieted at every call of stringRGB2HEX
   function _rgb2hex(rgb_string, r, g, b) 
   {
      //VERY IMPORTANT: by adding (1 << 24) we avoid 'rgb(0, 0, 0)' to be mistakenly converted into '#0'
      var rgb = (1 << 24) | (parseInt(r) << 16) | (parseInt(g) << 8) | parseInt(b); //same thing of: ( r + (256 * g) + (65536 * b) + 16777216)
      //toString(16) specify hex 16 radix, works only for numbers [source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwab3ed2(v=VS.85).aspx]   
      return '#' + rgb.toString(16).substr(1); //substr(1) because we have to remove the (1 << 24) added above
   }

   function stringRGB2HEX(string)
   {
      if(typeof string === 'string')
         string = string.replace(/rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)/g, _rgb2hex);
      return string;
   }
```

This one converts also rgb colors in complex styles like `background`.

A `style.background` value like: `"none no-repeat scroll rgb(0, 0, 0)"` is easily converted into `"none no-repeat scroll #000000"` by simply doing `stringRGB2HEX(style.background)`

Answer (score 1):

http://www.phpied.com/rgb-color-parser-in-javascript/

A JavaScript class that accepts a string and tries to figure out a valid color out of it. Some accepted inputs are for example:

```
* rgb(0, 23, 255)
* #336699
* ffee66
* fb0
* red
* darkblue
* cadet blue
```

Comment: `ffee66` and `fb0` are not valid colors in CSS. Maybe you should try it first.

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/29/convert-rgb-to-hex.aspx and i am using it in my project

Comment: The solution provided at the link is WRONG because converts "rgb(0, 0, 0)" into "#0" instead of "#000000", the reason is that the << operator does not shift bits if the value to shift is a zero.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go, this will allow you to use $(selector).getHexBackgroundColor() to return the hex value easily :**

```
$.fn.getHexBackgroundColor = function() {
    var rgb = $(this).css('background-color');
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    function hex(x) {return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);}
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}
```