# JQuery Color Picker

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, color-picker

I need to have a JQuery color Picker, where I can change the different HTML elements on a page. It should be easy to implement, I should be able to pick a color, enter RGB values and Hex values. Which plugin is the best hassle free to use.

Comment: https://github.com/tovic/color-picker is a tiny color picker plugin written in pure JavaScript. It is a hook-based plugin so you can simply create another function/class wrapper to extend your own custom features.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[This](http://acko.net/dev/farbtastic) jQuery plugin is quite simple. You can enter Hex value but there is no method for RGB (as seems from demo page).

Comment: I use this one in my projects, it's one of the most accurate and easy to use of the lot.

Comment: I use Fabtastic as well... check out this SO answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638948/background-color-hex-to-js-variable-jquery) on how to convert RGB to hex

Answer (score 8):

If you want to write in html5 you can use attribute type for input tag

usage:

```
<input type="color" name="helpme">
```

or

Try [this site](http://www.htmldrive.net/categorys/show/16/Color-Picker), It has bunch of color pickers. Choose which suits you best.

Answer (score 2):

http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/

Answer (score 1):

How about [`ColorPicker`](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/)? It allows you to enter hex/RGB/HSB, or click on a nice colour chart.

Answer (score 0):

What about [This](http://designreviver.com/tutorials/jquery-color-picker/) plugin

Comment: That plugin's pretty broken in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Farbtastic is my color picker of choice:
http://acko.net/blog/farbtastic-jquery-color-picker-plug-in/
The js file is only 10kb, or less than 5kb if you minify it.

Answer (score 0):

I have brought some of the MIT like jQuery [color picker on this website](http://bestcolorpicker.com). All of them have the links back to their original sites that have their implementation documentation in case you decide to use one of them.

But for which one is the "Best" one, you might have to judge it by yourself.