# jquery css color value returns RGB?

Tags: jquery, css, hex, rgb

In my CSS file:

```
a, a:link, a:visited { color:#4188FB; }
a:active, a:focus, a:hover { color:#FFCC00; }
```

I tried with:

```
var link_col = $("a:link").css("color");
alert(link_col); // returns rgb(65, 136, 251)
```

How can I get the HEX code?

*** edit: found the answer here:
[Background-color hex to JavaScript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638948/background-color-hex-to-js-variable-jquery)

Shame on me, could have search a bit better before posting..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/jquery-get-hex-value-rather-rgb

Comment: possible duplicate of [Background-color hex to JavaScript variable (jQuery)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638948/background-color-hex-to-javascript-variable-jquery)

Answer (score 8):

Some adjustes to function

```
$.fn.getHexBackgroundColor = function() {
    var rgb = $(this).css('background-color');
    if (!rgb) {
        return '#FFFFFF'; //default color
    }
    var hex_rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/); 
    function hex(x) {return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);}
    if (hex_rgb) {
        return "#" + hex(hex_rgb[1]) + hex(hex_rgb[2]) + hex(hex_rgb[3]);
    } else {
        return rgb; //ie8 returns background-color in hex format then it will make                 compatible, you can improve it checking if format is in hexadecimal
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**Here you go, this will allow you to use $(selector).getHexBackgroundColor() to return the hex value easily :**

```
$.fn.getHexBackgroundColor = function() {
    var rgb = $(this).css('background-color');
    rgb = rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
    function hex(x) {return ("0" + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2);}
    return "#" + hex(rgb[1]) + hex(rgb[2]) + hex(rgb[3]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take. Simple and concise.

```js
(function($) {
  $.fn.getHexBackgroundColor = function() {
    return (function(rgb) {
      return '#' + (!rgb
        ? 'FFFFFF'
        : rgb.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/)
             .slice(1)
             .map(x => ('0' + parseInt(x).toString(16)).slice(-2))
             .join('')
             .toUpperCase());
    })($(this).css('background-color'));
  }
})(jQuery);

$(function() {
  $('#color-rgb').text($('.foo').css('background-color'));
  $('#color-hex').text($('.foo').getHexBackgroundColor());
});
```

```css
.foo {
  background: #F74;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

label { font-weight: bold; }
label:after { content: ': '; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="foo"></div>
<label>RGB</label><span id="color-rgb">UNDEF</span><br />
<label>HEX</label><span id="color-hex">UNDEF</span>
```