# In JSColor, how do I get the hex of the color?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jscolor

Using JSColor, after the user picks a color, how do I get the "hex"?

```
$("input#colorpicker").css('background-color') => this returns background-color: rgb(107, 132, 255);
```

But not a hex.

Comment: Doesn't JSColor put the color HEX value into corrsponding input as a value? I mean `$("input#colorpicker").val()`.

Comment: @dfsq no it doesn't. val() returns nothing.

Comment: PLEASE share how you output this. I have the colorpicker running but I can't output the values

Answer (score 3):

I assume that jQuery.css returns the value that was set.
Try the following function to convert RGB to HEX:

```
function colorToHex(color) {
    if (color.substr(0, 1) === '#') {
        return color;
    }
    var digits = /(.*?)rgb\((\d+), (\d+), (\d+)\)/.exec(color);

    var red = parseInt(digits[2]);
    var green = parseInt(digits[3]);
    var blue = parseInt(digits[4]);

    var rgb = blue | (green << 8) | (red << 16);
    return digits[1] + '#' + rgb.toString(16);
};

colorToHex('rgb(120, 120, 240)')
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually upto an extent this depends on browser that it returns in rgb or hex, anyway check out this threads there are nice discussions about it and there are many solutions as well.

[Background-color hex to JavaScript variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638948/background-color-hex-to-javascript-variable-jquery)

and

[How to get hex color value rather than RGB value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/get-hex-value-rather-than-rgb-value-using-jquery)

and

[Can I force jQuery.css("backgroundColor") returns on hexadecimal format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177454/can-i-force-jquery-cssbackgroundcolor-returns-on-hexadecimal-format)

and

[jquery css color value returns RGB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3048838/jquery-css-color-value-returns-rgb)

Answer (score 0):

There is onchange event available:

```
$("input#colorpicker").change(function() {
    console.log(this.color);
});
```