# Jquery, getting .css "background-color" in #000000 format?

Tags: jquery, regex, html, background-color

I'm using a jquery plugin that seems to need the color in "000000" format but when I do this:

```
currentcolor = $("#" + dividediting).css("background-color");
```

I get the output as:

```
rgb(0,0,0)
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to change the way it outputs or if I have to use regex to parse the result to get it to the needed format.. thanks for any advice

Comment: I think you may have to parse it. Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740700/jquery-get-hex-value-rather-rgb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the browser returning the parsed and processed colour value, it's got nothing to do with jQuery as such.

If you need to convert the value, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638948/background-color-hex-to-javascript-variable-jquery)

`rgb(x,z,y)` is valid CSS as well, though.