# looping through table rows

Tags: jquery, css

I'm looking to loop through the rows of a table and checking to see what color they have for background. This is what I have so far:

```
var TheColor = "";

$('#MyTable tr').each(function () {
    TheColor = "";
    TheColor = $(this).attr('background-color');
    alert(TheColor);
});
```

When the loops unfolds, all I'm getting is "undefined" and I'm not seeing why. However, when I write TheColor = $(this).html(); I'm getting the expected output.

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: Does your "tr" really have a "background-color" attribute? You might should be looking at a style attribute with that property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to select it like:

```
$(this).css('background-color');
```

Since the attribute you are looking for is actually a style property (`style="background-color: red"`).

Comment: Indeed. `background-color` isn't an attribute on the `tr` element, it's a piece of style information. @frenchie: More: http://api.jquery.com/css/#css1

Comment: ok, this works. However, it's returning the values in the form of rgb(...). Do you know why it's not returning the data in the format of #FDFEGG ?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/638948/background-color-hex-to-javascript-variable-jquery

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#MyTable tr').map(function(item){ return item.css('background-color'); })
```

This will return an array of background colors with each element in the array representing the background color from the table.