# Want to test the Name of a background color in JQuery

Tags: jquery, background-color

I didnt find an answer that I could understand.  I am trying to test if a div that was clicked has a background color of 'red'  ... instead of red (in an alert) I am getting rgb(125,0,0) .... tried testing that with single quotes and it didnt work... any help please?

```
 alert($('#' + id).css('background-color'));

 if ($('#' + id).css('background-color') == 'red') {
                 $('#' + id).hide('slow');
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be a whole lot easier if you gave the divs the background color using a CSS class, then simply tested for the presence of the class.  Color is less semantic than the class, anyway.

```
 <style>
    .alert { background-color: Red; }
 </style>

 <div id="warning" class="alert">
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
       $('div').click( function() {
           if ($(this).hasClass('alert')) {
                $(this).hide('slow');
           }
       });
    });
 </script>
```

Comment: Ah crud, that makes so much more sense to do -- Ill just add a class to my red divs... thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Testing it in Chrome, I am getting spaces between those commas. If you are comparing strings, every character including spaces must be the same, so change to:

```
if ($('#' + id).css('background-color') == 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
```

Answer (score 2):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638948/background-color-hex-to-javascript-variable-jquery) may help to avoid any possible cross-browser difference.