# Find data from css in javascript

Tags: javascript

I define several color in css
now I want to get all the colors and to do some checks for example to build new objects with all the colors , in this case i want to have object with data of the colors of the first second and third in runtime
is it possible ?

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>

   p.first { color: gray; }
   p.second { color: red; }
   p.third { 
    background: purple;
    color: white;
   }

  </style>
</head>
<body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery](http://jquery.com/) makes this sort of thing trivial to do.

Once you have jQuery loaded, you can do something as simple as this (utilizing [jQuery.css](http://api.jquery.com/css/)):

```
var color = jQuery("p.first").css("color");
```

To set up an object as you state in your question:

```
var colors = {firstcolor:jQuery("p.first").css("color"), secondcolor:jQuery("p.second").css("color")};
```

NOTE: This will return RGB values.  To convert to hex, see [This Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638948/background-color-hex-to-javascript-variable-jquery/639030#639030)

Answer (score 1):

To do it without jQuery is also pretty easy:

```
var p = document.getElementsByTagName('p');
var first = p.getElementsByClassName('first');
console.log(first.item(0).style.color); // etc
```